# Downloading older version of diamondback?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am developing some ROS nodes based on July's version of diamondback, and I wanted to install same version of ROS.
So, I installed up-to-dated version of ROS diamondback, uniquely downloadable version, and there is some bugs that are difficult to debug; I spent more than two weeks to try to debug this.
Is there any way to get older version of diamondback?
Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12020/downloading-older-version-of-diamondback?/) by [SeongUk Han](https://answers.ros.org/users/847/seonguk-han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to check out an older version of ros, but it's not trivial at all. In theory you should never have to check out an older version of ros. Newer versions of a distribution only contain bugfixes that do not break the API.

So, if you want to try it anyway, here is what you should do:

- Check out an older version of the distro file you care about. E.g. check out "https://code.ros.org/svn/release/trunk/distros/diamondback.rosdistro" for diamondback.
- This rosdistro file specifies the version of each of the stacks you need to reconstruct the older release
- Now you could manually install all the right versions of all stacks, but that could be a lot of work, depending on how much of the distro you need. Alternatively, you can use the generate_rosinstall tool in the ros_release stack to automatically create a rosinstall file for you. The ros_release stack is here: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_release/trunk

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4